# How to hide a column on active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to hide a column based on their value using Active Admin.

So if id.field is null i don't want to show this column.

```
Index do
     column :name do |value|
        link_to value.id_field, name_path(value)
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be records that have this value, so you can't really hide the whole column base on one record (I hope it makes sense for you the way I explaind it). However you can hide the value from that cell:

```
Index do
  column :name do |value|
    link_to value.id_field, name_path(value) if value.id_field.present?
  end
end
```

or use active_admin's `status_tag`:

```
Index do
  column :name do |value|
    value.id_field.present? ? link_to(value.id_field, name_path(value)) : status_tag( "no link" )
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, this is the way I used it `s.accepted? ? status_tag('accepted', :ok) : status_tag('rejeceted', :error)`, in this case keYs`Ok` and `error` will render status tags in different colors. There are also `warning` and `success` tags. And may be info as well. Have to try it.

Comment: the link to resource now is name_path.1 instead name_path/1.. did you know why?